# Proving Fermat's Last Theorem (easily) using "assumed" conjectures

Tags: elliptic-curves

It can easily be proven assuming Szpiro's conjecture that Fermat's Last Theorem is true for sufficiently large $n$. The proof consists of extremely straightforward computations. My question is, is there a refinement of that proof that prove's FLT for *all* $n$? Or maybe, are there any other unproven conjectures (ABC conjecture, etc.) that if proven would lead to a simple proof of FLT? If so, what is the statement of the conjecture and what is the proof of FLT assuming this conjecture?
Thanks!

Comment: The abc conjecture only implies FLT for sufficiently large n. There are rumors that a proof is near completion.

Comment: For a reference to the result mentionned by Ragib, see Lang's *Algebra*. Also, assuming ABC, we can prove a weak form of FLT, namely, that there exists only finitely many primitive solutions (this also follows from Falting's theorem).

Comment: If abc conjecture implies Fermat's Last Theorem, then equivalent statements imply as well. See the list on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abc_conjecture#Some_consequences

Answer (score 5):

I think that an effective form of ABC will give an effective upper bound on $n$ for which $x^n + y^n = z^n$ has non-trivial solutions.  This would leave finitely many $n$ to check, which one could imagine (if the bound on $n$ is not too large) could be checked by other, more traditional means.